# How to select fields returned by GeoServer WMS GetFeatureInfo request? 

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I'm running simple local mapping service based on PostGIS/GeoServer/OpenLayers stack.

Following opengeo [tutorial](http://workshops.opengeo.org/stack-intro/openlayers.html#openlayers) I've tied click events in OpenLayers to WMS GetFeatureInfo call using:

```
    map.events.register('click', map, function (e) {
        var url = "http://localhost:1979/geoserver/wms" 
          + "?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo"
          + "&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml"
          + "&BBOX=" + map.getExtent().toBBOX()
          + "&X=" + e.xy.x
          + "&Y=" + e.xy.y
          + "&INFO_FORMAT=text/html"
          + "&QUERY_LAYERS=MYDATA:MYLAYER"
          + "&LAYERS=MYDATA:MYLAYER"
          + "&FEATURE_COUNT=5"
          + "&SRS=EPSG:3857"
          + "&STYLES="
          + "&WIDTH=" + map.size.w
          + "&HEIGHT=" + map.size.h;
        window.open(url,
          "getfeatureinfo",
          "location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,width=800,height=125"
        );
      });
```

I've used GeoServer's [FreeMarker](http://docs.geoserver.org/trunk/en/user/tutorials/freemarker.html) [templates](http://docs.geoserver.org/trunk/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html) to format the response correctly. The problem I have is that the response I get returns all of the fields from the layer.

Is there a way to select the ones that are relevant to the user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't look good ([source](http://www.mail-archive.com/geoserver-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00178.html)):

> ... GetFeatureInfo [...] is a WMS request and WFS. [...] One difference in their behaviour is that Geoserver sends always all the attributes with GetFeatureInfo but with WFS the list of attributes can be given in the request.

You could create a view that contains only the attributes your user wants to/should see and serve that through Geoserver.

An alternative would be to [adjust die GetFeatureInfo template](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html).

Comment: displaying or not displaying is one thing but radek want to return only some fields values. It makes a big difference regarding transfered data and security aspects.

Comment: That's why my first suggestion was to create a view.

Comment: More on using VIEWs [here](https://smathermather.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/postgresql-views-within-geoserver-getfeatureinfo-with-freemarker-templates-etc/).

Answer (score 7):

Just don't include the fields you don't want in your freemarker template. See http://docs.geoserver.org/trunk/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html#custom-templates

Comment: Good link, there is some real good documentation on the Geoserver site - This example I found useful (with a little fiddling around of course)for returning only the fields I wanted.

Comment: Correct link http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html#custom-templates

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using the GeoServer propertyName WMS request parameter:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#propertyname

Comment: For me this is the best solution! 1. Very simple! 2. I even have the possibility from other applications to make a full featureInfo. With the templates it isn´t possible any more! 3. And last but not least the network traffic is much smaller then requesting complete feature! Tank-you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditional statements to freemarker templates.

For example in your content.ftl file you can add something like this to only list "YOUR_FIELDNAME".

```
<#if attribute.name == "YOUR_FIELDNAME">
     <li>${attribute.name}: ${attribute.value}</li>
</#if>
```

Alternatively you can exclude a field by doing this:

```
<#if !attribute.name == "YOUR_FIELDNAME">
     <li>${attribute.name}: ${attribute.value}</li>
</#if>
```

Answer (score -2):

What about this?

> Also, for this to return attributes
>   (and not just the layer name and
>   feature id) you have to add
>   "ows_include_items" "attribute1, attribute2, ..., attributeN" 
>   or
>   "ows_include_items" "all" 
>   to the metadata section of your WMS layer's
>   map file entry.

From : http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/GetFeatureInfo

Comment: But Radek uses Geoserver, not UMN Mapserver, so there is no map file.

Comment: I've seen that. I've never used geoserver but I guess there is one way to set metadata as well, no?